# Differences in using Q vs When promise library for javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm fairly new to using promises in javascript. I specifically work in nodeJS and up to this point I've done mostly everything using callbacks. Now I'm working with a library that does everything primarily through promises and they recommend using [When](http://github.com/cujojs/when), but after doing some research I found [Q](http://github.com/kriskowal/q) which looks more popular. I believe its compatible with whichever library I use that follow the Promises/A+ standards – which they both do.

Is any one actually better than the other? If so, why?

Comment: The correct link for Q is this https://github.com/kriskowal/q . Please update.

Comment: Q is older thats why is more popular.

Comment: @hardcoresquirrel thanks for catching that, updated.